# NoReverseMatch Issue (Tango With Django 1.7 [10.5])

Tags: python, django

I am in the process of teaching myself django, and have run into an error I haven't been able to troubleshoot myself. I have tried some of the recommendations found in similarly asked StackExchange answers, but haven't been successful.

**Question:**

I am attempting to use the url template tag as follows:

*index.html*

```
...
{% if categories %}
    <ul>
        {% for category in categories %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'rango:category' category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
{% endif %}
...
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w]+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^restricted/$', views.restricted, name='restricted'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    )
```

*views.py*

```
def category(request, category_name_slug):

    context_dict = {}

    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        context_dict['category_name'] = category.name

        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        context_dict['pages'] = pages

        context_dict['category'] = category

        context_dict['slug'] = category_name_slug
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rango:category', args=context_dict))
    #^ not working
```

On accessing localhost:8000/rango, I receive the following error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /rango/

Reverse for 'category' with arguments '(u'other-frameworks',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'rango/category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\\w]+)/$']
```

What have I done wrong??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of your regexp that's supposed to match `'other-frameworks'` is `[\w]+`. `\w` does not match `-`, so no pattern matches that slug. Add `-` to your patterns if you want them to match slugs, eg `[-\w]+`.